# What are the conclusions to be drawn when a t-test is significant but a linear mixed effects model is not?

Tags: mixed-model, t-test, random-variable, random-effects-model

I have 30 participants. They have a pre score and a post score. I am testing whether this changes. There are five observations per participant.

When the data are analyzed using a t-test there is a significant difference. When analyzed using linear mixed effects (i.e., with random subject and item intercepts) there is no significant difference (using the lmerTest package in R to generate p values via Satterthwaite's degrees of freedom method).

What conclusions can I draw from the difference between results?

Comment: Could you be more specific about how you are employing a t-test with such data?

Comment: @whuber Sure! The t-test would be on each participant's mean pre-training score compared to their mean post-training score.

Comment: Dave, can you please clarify how "five observations per participant" translates to "a pre score and a post score?" In typical use Pre/Post pretty specifically means *two* observations.

Comment: @Alexis Sure! It was actually six observations per participant. Three of these were pre-intervention (i.e., measured our DV using three different stimuli pre intervention) and then three were post-intervention.

Comment: Nice username ;) It would be helpful if you posted your code.

Comment: That doesn't sound like "a t-test:" it sounds like *30* t-tests.  The difference isn't trivial, because it's crucial to compensate for making all those tests at once.  Moreover, 30 tests do not assess whether there is a significant difference overall: it's making a determination about each participant separately.

Comment: @whuber I'm not sure what gives the impression that there are 30 t-tests? We compared the average pre-intervention score of 30 participants to their post-intervention score.

Comment: The reason I had that impression is that combining the scores as you did violates a fundamental assumption of all t-tests: namely, that the data are independent.  The only t-tests that might be valid are the person-specific comparisons of before and after responses.

Answer (score 2):

Measurements on the same subjects are correlated. If you ignore these correlations, and you perform a simple t-test as you did, then you expect that

- p-values are wrongly too small for between-subjects effects, and
- p-values are wrongly too large for within-subjects effects

The reason is that the variance of correlated data does not equal to the variance of independent data, assumed by the standard (unpaired) t-test.

If interested, you may find more information in Section 1.2 of my [course notes](http://www.drizopoulos.com/courses/EMC/CE08.pdf).